# Looping taxonomy in taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, loop, taxonomy

So I have a CPT of references (like a dictionary kind of format for music).

In it there are two taxonomies: `medium_reference` and `reference_letter`.

The `reference_letter` lists letters A-Z, while `medium_reference` lists through the type of reference type it is (person, terminology, company).

I was wondering if it was possible to loop through each letter, and then in that loop, loop through the individual terms.

Something like this (not that this works in anyway possible):

```
$reference_letters = get_the_terms($post->ID,'reference_letter');
$reference_types = get_the_terms($post->ID,'medium_reference');

if($reference_letters) {
    // Loop through letters
    foreach($reference_letters as $reference_letter => $letter) {

        if($reference_types) {
            // Loop through individual terms
            foreach($reference_types as $reference_type => $type) {
                the_title(); // And other attributes
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Does that make sense? And is it possible without having to run multiple `get_posts()` for each letter?

Comment: Check this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97923/combine-two-taxonomies-in-a-hierarchical-tree

Comment: Well, technically speaking, there's nothing wrong with your approach. It's even better (faster) to run multiple small queries, then a single large one.

Comment: @TeddMagwell thanks for that, but it only loops the taxonomies not posts too

Comment: @DanStefancu yeah I was just hoping to minimise the coding more than anything - also curious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into trouble like I did, I figured it out!

```
$taxonomy_1 = get_terms( 'taxonomy_1', $args_1 );
$taxonomy_2 = get_terms( 'taxonomy_2', $args_2 );

    foreach( $taxonomy_1 as $tax_1 ) {

        foreach( $taxonomy_2 as $tax_2 ) {

            $posts = get_posts(
                array(
                    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                    'post_type'        => 'ENTER-YOUR-CPT',
                    'order'            => 'ASC',
                    'orderby'          => 'title',
                    'taxonomy'         => $tax_2->taxonomy,
                    'term'             => $tax_2->slug,
                )
            );

            foreach( $posts as $post ) {
                setup_postdata( $post ); 
                // ENTER YOUR OWN LOOP the_title(), the_permalink(), etc.
            }
        }
    }
```

In my case, `$taxonomy_1` was my letter (reference_letter) and `$taxonomy_2` was my type (medium_reference).

Also in this method, it sorts the posts into their taxonomies based on two `$tax_2->` lines in the `get_posts()`.